# How do I bind textures to textureUnit in LWJGL

Tags: opengl, textures, shader

I now know how to work with sampler2D objects in openGL shader code but I want to use that in LWJGL and cannot find any simple code or tutorial on the Internet where there are shown just the important lines to do so. I know that you have to bind the unit number to the location of the sampler2D unit with

```
int loc = getUniformAdress(uniformName);
glUniform1i(loc, unitNr);
```

And then I also found code segments like

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + unitNr);
```

And finally I got to know that after all that you have to bind the integer value of your texture to the unit by

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureLoc);
```

But for me its still not clear how to mix all this up and also how to get the picture loaded and have the textureLoc value available.

Can someone who has basic knowledge with this maybe just give me a code example how to do this? I dont need shader coder or sth like that, just how to bind a texture file (maybe PNG) to the shader.

Answer (score 1):

I don't write much Java, but suspect that the sequence for OpenGL calls is the same across different languages.

Initialisation is required to do at least once in the program run, usually at the beginning.

1. Select a texture unit with glActiveTexture. All subsequent calls will effect this unit.
2. Create a texture object, bind it with glBindTexture.
3. Setup texture parameters like filtering mode, clamping mode etc, and provide image with glTexImage2d.
4. Setup all other things like shader programs etc.

In your render frame function:

1. Choose a program object that uses a texture with glUseProgram
2. Rebind textures to the texture units if necessary(if your layout is not constantly changing, the initialisation made previously is enough) with glActiveTexture/glBindTexture.
3. use glUniform* functions to setup uniforms(again, if your layout is not changing, you can move this to the initialisation)

Other sequences are also possible. I also suggest to look at http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Sampler#Binding_textures_to_samplers for another example.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but can you maybe tell me what `glGenTextures()` does, I often found this but have no idea if I need it or not...

Comment: creates a texture identificator(s) to be used in glBindTexture call. like all others glGen* functions(a ton of them), is called whenever new GL object is to be created

Comment: suggest to read about opengl(you find some links in the 'opengl' tag info) as what you are asking amounts to the very basics of opengl API